# Why is my app 25% larger on the App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store

The zip file I uploaded is 19.5MB, but on the App Store, Apple reports it as 24.5MB -- too large for over-the-air downloading. Is Apple adding a 5MB wrapper? Decompressing and recompressing less efficiently? Using 815K "megabytes"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [App size on app store is much larger than uploaded app size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42478186/app-size-on-app-store-is-much-larger-than-uploaded-app-size)

Comment: @this.myself That's a slightly different question, i.e., why is my app **enormously** larger on the App Store. The [answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42481125/27358) is just a less well-referenced version of [FreeAsInBeer's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5264491/27358), and I'm not sure it does actually provide an adequate explanation.

Comment: Yes, questions are different but the meaning is equivalent, IMHO. Unfortunatly it is hard to get adequate explanation with Apple Developer things (as Apple Help is the only soure).

Comment: @this.myself if so, I'd say that question should be closed as a duplicate of this one, which is older and has a slightly more informative accepted answer. but see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67274104/27358) on the other one -- I do think that question is more specific. I'll edit the title of this question to be more general, and the title of the other to be more specific.

Comment: Changing the other the other questions title, may be also tuning the question itself, seems like a good option to me. Your answer over there contains some valueable information.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From Apple:

> When your application is approved by
> Apple to sell on the App Store, it is
> encrypted for DRM purposes and
> re-compressed. When the encryption is
> added, the size of the compressed file
> will increase. The exact size of the
> increase will vary from app to app,
> however, the size increase can be
> large when the binary contains a lot
> of contiguous zeros. We are unable to
> guarantee the size of your file after
> the encryption has been added.

Source (Expand section [*View the file sizes of a build (iOS, tvOS)*](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/?lang=en#/dev3b56ce97c))

Comment: Or paraphrased: Encrypted data compresses poorly.

Answer (score 2):

Download the app from the App Store with iTunes. You should end up with a .ipa in `~/Music/iTunes/Mobile Applications` which is (hopefully) approximately what you get from the App Store. Check its size. You can additionally use something like `unzip -Z myapp.zip` to check the compressed size of individual files (an .ipa is just a .zip).

If, as in FreeAsInBeer's answer, your executable's compressed size is increasing loads, then it might be worthwhile trying to fix this (5 MB is a lot of code). Compiling with `-Os` might be helpful.

Also note that the .ipa will have some additional info, namely iTunesArtwork (from the up-to-512x512 App Store app icon) and iTunesMetadata.plist (which has stuff like the App Store category) and some FairPlay information. I'm not sure which of these are sent to the device.

And finally, Apple might be using M = 10<sup>6</sup> instead of 2<sup>20</sup> — 19.5×2<sup>20</sup> ≈ 20.4×10<sup>6</sup> . IIRC this was one of the changes in Snow Leopard.