# App size on app store is 7x larger than uploaded app size

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, ipa, itunes-store

When i uploaded my iOS app to app-store, the ipa size was **32 MB**. Now my app goes live, now i i checked my app size on app store, it is showing **237 MB** on iphone 6, it is showing **252 MB** size when i open app link in browser on my PC.

Why this much difference in size of app. Any suggestions?

Comment: 237 MB on your iPhone 6 or in the AppStore description?

Comment: IPAs (what you submit) are just zips. That is the reason I asked about the Appstore description file size. If you open the file you submitted to Apple, you may see if it is a big file because e.g. you have big text files.

Comment: @Injuanj: in app store description

Answer (score 5):

From Apple:

> When your application is approved by Apple to sell on the App Store, it is encrypted for DRM purposes and re-compressed. When the encryption is added, the size of the compressed file will increase. The exact size of the increase will vary from app to app, however, the size increase can be large when the binary contains a lot of contiguous zeros. We are unable to guarantee the size of your file after the encryption has been added.

Source (Expand section *View the file sizes of a build (iOS, tvOS)*:
https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/?lang=en#/dev3b56ce97c

Answer (score 0):

The current Apple docs on "[Reducing Your App’s Size](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/reducing_your_app_s_size)" suggest that

> compared to the binary you uploaded, the final size of your app after it’s approved for the App Store may end up being **slightly larger**. *[emphasis added]*

A 7x-8x increase seems like an extraordinarily large difference to be explained by simple encryption/recompression, but there are pathological cases. It would be good to know what the uncompressed size of the IPA is, and if there are particular files in the uncompressed version that happen to compress very well, that might compress badly after being encrypted.

If so, compressing those *before* including them in the IPA and decompressing them at run-time might save significant space -- Apple suggests something like that on their “[advanced optimization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/reducing_your_app_s_size/doing_advanced_optimization_to_further_reduce_your_app_s_size)” page, where they talk about compressing images and audio files.

There's also general advice there and on the “[basic optimization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/reducing_your_app_s_size/doing_basic_optimization_to_reduce_your_app_s_size)” page about using [asset catalogs](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/index.html?localePath=en.lproj#/dev10510b1f7) and [app thinning](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/11.0/index.html?localePath=en.lproj#/devde46df08a) to minimize bundling resources that might be unnecessary for a particular device, but that doesn't sound like the problem here.